# Go forward in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have 2 views, A and B. A is a tableview, and B is a detail view. When a cell is tapped in view A, the appropriate data is loaded in view B and I use [self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller] to present it. This all works fine, but if the user presses row 10, lets view B load, goes back, and presses row 10 again, I would like for it to just go forward to the view B that is already loaded. The navigationcontroller always lists as only having one view in the stack. Do I have to manually save a view to the navigationcontroller to re-present? The project uses ARC and Storyboard if that makes a differance. Thanks

Comment: Aren't you popping when you go back? Why would you expect the stack to still have the element you just popped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this actually you dont even have to concern yourself with `navigationcontroller`. Have a `UIViewController` variable (lets say `lastViewController`) in your `ViewController1` where `viewA` and `viewB` reside.

Before pushing `ViewController2` the detailed view store that reference in `lastViewController`. When you pop back and press another row, check if its that same viewController and show the same viewController.

But I would advise against this approach. Keep it simple, let `ViewControllerB` load again. There could be a scenario where loading again is preferential as it might show the user more latest information row10.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are seeing is correct! When ViewController B is needed it is created and pushed onto the stack of the navigation controller and we see view B. When the user goes back to ViewController A and we see view A, ViewController B is no longer needed, and it and its view go out of existence.

This is efficient and lightweight and makes perfect sense. Once you are back in ViewController A and view A, who knows what row the user will tap now? If the user taps row 10 and goes back to A, taps row 10 and goes back to A, over and over, a new ViewController B will be created and go out of existence each time. So what? From the user's point of view it is perfectly consistent; it *looks* like the same view B! That is all that matters. You don't *want* to go back to the *same* view B; you want to create view B all over again. And that is what you do.

Indeed, this is the genius of iOS. With a single tiny screen, it is able to make views come and go without burdening memory and other resources.

For more about UINavigationController architecture, which is what you're using here (master-detail), see my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_navigation_controllers